# Sorting in a combobox in vb.net sorts tilde before alpha characters - What can I use to sort higher than alphas?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program that fills comboboxes with lists from data I provide in program resources.  (ex: U.S. National Parks quarters).  I have to allow that some entries can occur where a user has a data item for which they know the year but not the state.  (there were multiple state quarters released each year during the program).  For those cases, I want the user to be able to select a value ~Unkn to signify that the entry year is known but not the particular state for that year.

I'm entering the values from my own database and I did not have all of the information when I created this database.  Now I'm entering the database information into my program and I want to process all coins and then go back and find those few that I did not have all details for at the time of database creation.   My presentation lists show the year and the state and the national park name.  If I only know the year, I want to be able to specify ~Unkn.  I selected the tilde because it is the highest ASCII printable character in the ASCII chart and I figured it would sort to the very end of any of my lists.

I'm putting my selection list into comboboxes with the SORTED property set to TRUE.  Everything works great except for the tilde sorting first which is not how I want this to work.  I want this list item at the end of all lists.  I'm not married to the tilde but I prefer it and I'm hoping there is some trick I don't know to make this work. I had tried the underscore (ASCII 95) first but that did not work as I had hoped.  I had not taken case into account.

Can anyone show me how to accomplish this or explain why it cannot be done as I prefer.  I have seen elsewhere people discussing UNICODE as being at root of a similar problem but I researched that and I don't think that is what is causing my problem.  I'm stuck.

Thanks for any light you can shed

egb
.

Comment: Would a listbox do instead of a combobox? You could sort the list items before adding them to the display control - you get complete control over how the items are sorted that way. For example, `yourList.Sort(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` may well be what you want.

Comment: Show some of the code where you load your ComboBox(es). Is the tilde a part of the resulting data set that is bound to the ComboBox, or are you adding it in after fetching the list data?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a list before being added to the ComboBox, you can sort it yourself instead of using the control's `.Sorted` property:

```
Dim a As New List(Of String) From {"C", "b", "~", "_"}
a.Sort(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
ComboBox1.DataSource = a
```

[image: A combobox with the items sorted according to the code]

---

Docs:

[List.Sort Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8)

[StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase)

Comment: I use the sort property because it is fastest and easiest... just how I have always done things.  I have continued to research this and believe I'm finding out that this is just how things work under the hood.  What I will probably do is use a method to sort the data, put it into an unsorted combobox and just add the needed entry to the end of the list.  My code is only reading a resource file and plopping it into the combobox.  Nothing exotic..  Thanks for the input.  I was hoping there was some clever technique.  Seems it works as designed.